# Why does pre_get_posts() return "date" as the orderby parameter for every sortable column?

Tags: order, pre-get-posts, columns

I am stuck trying to get a custom column to sort according to a custom field.  I have two custom post types: Brand and Product.  I would like the Product admin screen to have a "Brand" column, and for that "Brand" column to be sortable by the custom field `_wpcf_belongs_brand-listing_id`.

I was able to successfully add a new "Brand" column to the "Product" admin screen

I then successfully registered the Brand column as sortable.  The "Brand" custom column has a key of `brand` and a value of `_wpcf_belongs_brand-listing_id`, which is the custom field I want to sort by.

```
//Register the Brand column in the Product admin page as sortable.    
add_filter( 'manage_edit-eproduct_sortable_columns', 'vendia_sortable_brand_column');

function vendia_sortable_brand_column( $sortable_columns ){
    $sortable_columns[ 'brand' ] = '_wpcf_belongs_brand-listing_id';
    debug($sortable_columns);
    return $sortable_columns;
}
```

To confirm the above function worked correctly, I use a `debug()` function that sends the output of `print_r()` to Firebug's console.
The `debug()` function output is:

```
Array
    (
        [title] => title
        [parent] => parent
        [comments] => comment_count
        [date] => Array
            (
                [0] => date
                [1] => 1
            )
        [brand] => _wpcf_belongs_brand-listing_id
    )
```

So I know that the "Brand" custom column is registered correctly.

However, my "Brand" custom column sort function is not working.  I would like to sort this column by the custom field `_wpcf_belongs_brand-listing_id`.

```
//Tell WordPress what to sort by in the Brand column of the Product admin page.
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'vendia_brand_column_orderby' );
function vendia_brand_column_orderby( $query ) {

    if( ! is_admin() )
        return;

    $orderby = $query->get( 'orderby' );
    echo $orderby;

    if( '_wpcf_belongs_brand-listing_id' == $orderby ) {
        $query->set('meta_key','_wpcf_belongs_brand-listing_id');
        $query->set('orderby','meta_value');
    }

}
```

For some reason I don't understand, my debugging statement of `echo $orderby;` returns a value of `date` for the key `orderby` for every sortable column.  I was the expecting `orderby` parameter to take on the values of "title", "parent", "comment_count", "date", and "_wpcf_belong_brand-listing_id".  Those are the values associated with each custom column key, output by my debugging function above.

According to 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

`date` is simply the default value for the `orderby` parameter of `WP_Query`.  So it seems like the WP_Query has not been changed from its defaults at this point, meaning, at the point that `pre_get_posts` fires.  However, every example I have seen that discusses adding a custom column, and making it sortable, uses `pre_get_posts` for changing the `orderby` parameter for the custom columns.

So am I using the wrong WordPress action (pre_get_posts) to change the `orderby` parameter for custom columns ?  If not, why is my WP_Query returning `date` as the `orderby` parameter for every custom column?

Thank you for your help.  I know this was a really long question.

Comment: Try checking for `$query->is_main_query()` also - eg `if( ! is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() ) return;` ...

Comment: That did it @bonger.  Thanks so much.  Struggled with this for days.  Wish you made this an answer so I could upvote it.